# Looking for recent fantasy novel set in New Orleans alternate history involving faerie incursion and curtain protecting earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read the first in what will become a series involving a female human protaganist who lives in New Orleans after an invasion of earth by Faerie.  The invasion was pushed back and earth is protected by a magical curtain.  Humans with magic are persecuted and the remaining non humans live in a controlled area. There is an attempt to reopen the curtain which was not successful.  I want to find out the writer so I can keep my eye out for the next books in the series.  Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: bits and pieces of this sound like the *Genesis of Shannarra* series by Terry Brooks, but the part about humans being persecuted don't sounds familiar...

Comment: I read Terry Brooks but this is by a female author whose name I can't remember.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Does the novel deal with the fallout from Hurricane Katrina?

Comment: I don't remember that being a significant plot line in the book.  It mostly shows the struggles of a post invasion New Orleans and US where the population is smaller, resources and food is scarce and paranoia about those who have power is everwhere.

Comment: hrm ok. it turns out there is a remarkably large number of similar fantasy novels written by women and set in New Orleans. Does the story have more of a "fantasy romance" feel or an "urban fantasy/detective/adventure" feel?

Comment: Actually both because the lead character has to figure out the truth concerning the invasion/curtain/non-human maltreatment to assist in preventing a reopening of the curtain.   There is a relationship that does develop with a faerie as part of the plot line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Veil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0118MR2S6)* by Chloe Neill

[image: Book cover for Veil]

> Seven years ago, the Veil that separates us from what lies beyond was torn apart, and New Orleans was engulfed in a supernatural war. Now, those with paranormal powers have been confined in a walled community that humans call the District. Those who live there call it Devil's Isle.
>
> Claire Connolly is a good girl with a dangerous secret: she's a Sensitive, a human endowed with magic that seeped through the Veil. Claire knows that revealing her skills would mean being confined to Devil's Isle. Unfortunately, hiding her power has left her untrained and unfocused.

It's set in New Orleans. It involves a fairy invasion with an energy wall that isolates New Orleans. And it's got a female protagonist who is part of the persecuted group of humans with powers.

Found with Google keywords of `fantasy novel "new orleans" fairy invasion`

Comment: Found with Google keywords of *fantasy novel  "new orleans" fairy invasion*

Comment: Lol to the 'let me google that for you' - almost makes you wonder if this is an attempt at promotion

Comment: @NKCampbell: ^_^ It took me about three iterations of search queries to find it, so it was not obvious. I just always like to share the search query when I can because some people see the `story_identification` tag as being something where you need encyclopaedic knowledge to be able to answer them.

Comment: Thank you very much I did try Google search too but obviously did have the correct search words!